# Generate Rows and Apply Formulas to Sheet from Defined Numeric Value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I've checked everywhere I can think of and can't find a decent answer to this problem (though I am relatively new to this and may have missed something obvious).

I have a Google Form where one of the questions is "number of users". I want to use this value in the associated Google Sheet to generate multiple rows of users in a separate sheet while applying an existing formula to those rows. 
So, for a simplified example, in the Google Sheet fed from the Google Form, the A column is "Location ID" and the B column is "Number of Users".

I would like a second Sheet to feed from this data while maintaining existing formulas on the second sheet. So that if "Location ID" is "CHI" and the "Number of Users" is "4", the ultimate auto-generated output is a column like this in the second sheet:

USER ID

CHI-User-1

CHI-User-2

CHI-User-3

CHI-User-4

I'm already doing most of this using formulas in the sheet itself, I'm just trying to auto-generate multiple rows using the value of one field (the number) while filling one column with a value (CHI) and leaving the formulas for the rest of the sheet intact (which concatenates the information together).

So, column A could just be four numbered rows, column B would be pre-filled with "User", column C would be the form-defined "CHI" while column D would be the formula to concatenate the three cells together.

This is a vastly simplified version of what I'm trying to do, but if I can get a direction it would be enormously helpful. (I'm also open to accomplishing the same task in a completely different way, this is just what I have at the moment.)

Comment: please provide some working code in order to make your question clearer and more concise.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that you are open to different approaches, here is one option.

Use an array formula to generate the user names. Suppose your responses came in looking like this:

[image]

Then you could generate the lists of users using a formula like this entered in A1 of the second sheet and pulled across

```
=ArrayFormula(if(row(indirect("1:"&index(Sheet1!$B:$B,column()+1)))=1,"User_ID",
index(Sheet1!$A:$A,column()+1)&"-User-"&row(indirect("1:"&index(Sheet1!$B:$B,column()+1)))-1))
```

[image]

Comment: I'll need to play with it and figure out how it actually works, but if that does the job I'll be thrilled. If nothing else you've shown me how to generate multiple rows based on a value, which was the biggest sticking point. And if I can't figure it out, I'll be back. Thanks!